Django: Templates template not found when attempting to access function rendering template
Second update
So I decided to start from scratch, replicating what I did and everything works.
Looking back, the only things I didn't do this time:

Rename some of the files and folders to correct a typo.  I tried to fix each references in all the files such as apps but whatever I did I either missed one or the change did not get recognized

Move files around in Finder to get them to correct locations


Moral of the story - sometimes it's better to start over if you've made changes manually to stuff.  Onward to next challenge...
Update:
So I changed the file path to:
Resilience_Radar_R2/Leadership_Questions_App/templates/Leadership_Questions/questions.html
When I go to:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Leadership_Questions_App/riskindex/
I still get an error:
    TemplateDoesNotExist at /Leadership_Questions_App/riskindex/
/questions.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Leadership_Questions_App/riskindex/
Django Version: 5.0.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
/questions.html
Exception Location: /Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  Leadership_Questions_App.views.riskindex
Python Executable:  /Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.12.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python '
 'Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R2',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python '
 'Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 11 Aug 2024 01:10:17 +0000
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.


Old issue:
I have a file structure:
Resilience_Radar_R2/Leadership_Questions_App/Leadership_Questions/templates/questions.html
I have defined a function, riskindex, that should render questions.html and include some text on the page.
I also have an index function that simply sends an HttpResponse if teh request is blank
The index function works fine at http://127.0.0.1:8000/Leadership_Questions_App/
but the riskindex at http://127.0.0.1:8000/Leadership_Questions_App/riskindex returns an error:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /Leadership_Questions_App/riskindex/
Leadership_Questions/questions.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Leadership_Questions_App/riskindex/
Django Version: 5.0.7
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Leadership_Questions/questions.html
Exception Location: /Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  Leadership_Questions_App.views.riskindex
Python Executable:  /Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.12.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python '
 'Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R2',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python312.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/xxx/Documents/Work/Python '
 'Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 10 Aug 2024 19:44:06 +0000

Terminal directory is:
(.venv) (base) xxx@MacBook-Pro Reslience_Radar_R2 %
It appears to be looking in  different directory than the one where the python code resides.
Reslience_Radar_R2 urls.py
rom django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Leadership_Questions_App/', include("Leadership_Questions_App.urls"))
]

Leadership_Questions_App
urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("riskindex/", views.riskindex, name="riskindex"),
    
]

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Leadership Questions")

def riskindex(request):
    description = "This is text"
    return render (request, "Leadership_Questions/questions.html", {
        "text": description
        }
        )

Leradership_Questions_App/templates questions.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leadership Questions</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        {{ description }}

    </body>
</html>

templates in settings.py:
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

I tried changing the path for the riskindex function and got the same error:
def riskindex(request):
    description = "This is text"
    return render (request, "questions.html", {
        "text": description
        }
        )

I've tried deleting the index function and path: and having the riskindex function be for the blank path but I get the same "Template not found" error:
Internal Server Error: /Leadership_Questions_App/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/beyondscorecard/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/beyondscorecard/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/beyondscorecard/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R2/Leadership_Questions_App/views.py", line 10, in riskindex
    return render (request, "Leadership_Questions/questions.html", {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/beyondscorecard/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 25, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/beyondscorecard/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/beyondscorecard/Documents/Work/Python Projects/Dashboard/Reslience_Radar_R1/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: Leadership_Questions/questions.html
[10/Aug/2024 19:55:14] "GET /Leadership_Questions_App/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78688



I have a file structure:
Resilience_Radar_R2/Leadership_Questions_App/Leadership_Questions/templates/questions.html

The app itself contains a directory named template. So it should be:
Resilience_Radar_R2/Leadership_Questions_App/templates/Leadership_Questions/questions.html


Note: Python modules are normally written in snake_case, not PascalCase, so it
should be leadership_questions, not Leadership_Questions_App.


Thanks.  However, when I moved the folders and files around to match the new directory, I now get a different error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using engine django:
This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.

@Jlv: can you edit the question with the updated error message?

Error aded to question, thanks

I think you forgot to add that new app to installed_apps list.
your installed_apps should look like this:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "Leadership_Questions_App",
]

